# Unable to access the properties of array in react JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to create an array and call its object properties in index.jsx file by importing the file, but it gives me error that

**Cannot read property 'imgsrcs' of undefined**

**Index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Sdata from './Sdata';
ReactDOM.render(
    <Card imgsrc={Sdata[0].imgsrcs}
    />,document.getElementById("root"));
```

**Sdata.jsx**

```
const Sdata= [
    {
        imgsrcs: "some",
        titles :"Flowers Blossom",
    },
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const Sdata= [
    {
        imgsrcs: "some",
        titles :"Flowers Blossom",
    },
];
export default Sdata;
```

Exporting array in this way also works!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you didn't export Sdata from Sdata.jsx.
You can export it like this:

```
export const Sdata= [
    {
        imgsrcs: "some",
        titles :"Flowers Blossom",
    },
];
```

And import it like this:

```
import { Sdata } from './Sdata';
```

OR just edit Sdata.jsx

```
const Sdata= [
    {
        imgsrcs: "some",
        titles :"Flowers Blossom",
    },
];
export default Sdata;
```

Comment: I don't see why there would be destructuring on the `import`; the only thing exported is the array itself.

Comment: it works Jakov! thank you, i forget to export an array.